# Is there any 15-16 inch screen sized gaming laptop with gtx 970m with?

Tags: laptop, gaming, graphics-cards

I am looking to buy a gaming laptop. I own a 15.6 inch laptop and it works perfectly fine for me. I don't travel much either so a 17 inch laptop is also not a problem, but as a last resort of my online research I want to see if there is any 15-16 inch laptop. My eyes are set on this laptop, I wish I could find an exact same laptop like this, but with 15-16 inch screen size.

[Asus ROG G751JT-WH71](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015QZVAF2)

Also for the given price range around $1200 or less, is there any better gaming laptop that you would recommend? I also plan to use it for media creation like stuff from Adobe products, and 3D stuff from Maya, Blender etc.

Thanks

Comment: @JetStream If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'll post what I said in the comment as an answer too.

I suggest you to buy the **MSI Apache Pro** with the **i7 6700HQ and GTX 970M** because this is what you wanted. As for rendering the i7 is way better than the i5 because of more cores and therefore better Multithreading.

The HDD that is built in is with 1TB big enough and you wont find many Laptops that offer more.

As for gaming MSI should be very good. They jsut produce gear for gaming and their products are very well made. Most MSI products can also be upgraded easily. In an older MSI gaming Laptop I bought on ebay you could add an extra fan and extra HDD.

So I would suggest you to buy this ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your updated answer. I am still waiting for other people's choices, but I think this is probably the only laptop with 970m and a 15-16 inch screen. But I also found some other laptops like in Dell Inspiron series and Asus ROG series, where they had a 960m gpu and rest all specs were same. Now from what I see, all these laptops with 960m are in my price range, but they have better build quality than the MSI that you mentioned(read the reviews about MSI)? So should I go for 970m or 960m considering the build quality?

Comment: Well I also saw the Asus ROG ones with the GTX 960 - and personally I would go for them. Asus has high quality standards and their products are mostly very durable. When I build a PC I always try to get Asus products. They seem to test everything very well before delivering it. But if you think you need a bit more performance use the 970 - I don't know MSI so their products can be very good as well in terms of how they are made. Just read through some more reviews or something like that, maybe someone here knows more about MSI and maybe also about Asus computers and can compare them :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cannot comment thus I write here: becarful, in the MSI Apache Pro link given by JetStream, the first (and less expensive version) is using a i5. According to what you want to do (media work with Adobe suite etc. wich, in addition to a good GPU, will take advantage of the 2 additionals cores provided by the i7 over the i5), I'd rather go for the i76700HQ/GTX970 version ;) its still in your price range ! (indeed, it has 1TB HDD instead of 256GB SSD, but you can still change that later)

To answer to your question about MSI: yes, it is a really good brand. There products (espcially laptops) are not that beautiful but the best adjective I'd use for them is "robust" :)

Comment: Well I did notice that on the first glance. Now I have one more doubt. How to know if a processor has 2 cores or 4 cores? I mean on all these amazon, jet etc sites, all we find is the processor name, something like Core i7-6700HQ or something. So how to deduce if a particular processor has 2 cores or 4 cores and also what processor speed(like 2.6 GHz) mean?

Comment: @Blasttrash You can see the amount of cores in the `product information` or `product details` - and as it seems the i5 as well as the i7 have 4 cores ("Prozessor Count")

Comment: My bad, didn't see that ;) on the same topic, notice that the i5 doesn't have hyperthreading :)